# How can I configure the kate editor to use only the filename and not the full file path for selection of file type

Tags: makefile, text-editor, kate

I am using Kate 3.14.8 to edit various file types including Makefiles and Python scripts. Consider that I have the following directory structure and files created by a test-runner:

```
Makefile.x86_64-linux.tmp/run/OUTPUT
Makefile.x86_64-linux.tmp/run/script.py
```

Any file in a path containing the pattern `Makefile.*` somewhere as a parent directory name, is considered by Kate as `Other/Makefile`. This can be seen by the checked option in `Tools` > `Mode` after opening a file.

**Expectation:** In the above example I would expect `Mode=Normal` for `OUTPUT` and `Mode=Script/Python` for `script.py`, but both have `Mode=Other/Makefile`.

I tried to change the behaviour by configuring the file extensions for the file types in `Settings`  > `Configure - Kate` > `Open/Save` > `Modes&Filetypes`. But I could not figure out how I have to change the `File extensions` field for `Other/Makefile` to only check the filename and not the full path.

**My question is:** Is it even possible to change the following default entry for `File extensions` to only search the basename and not the dirname? If it is, how can it be done?

```
GNUmakefile;Makefile;makefile;GNUmakefile.*;Makefile.*;makefile.*
```

The `.`appears to be treated literally and `*` appears to expand greedy.
I tried adding something like `Makefile[^/]*`, but then normal Makefiles with suffixes are not recognized anymore (e.g. `Makefile.default`)

My current workaround is to make the last patterns more specific like `Makefile.def*` to not match the `./Makefile.x86_64-linux.tmp/run/some_file`. But I have to add any patterns I encounter in my colleagues code bases manually.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!